# How to install adobe flash player in ubutu 15.04 LTS for google chrome?

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, google-chrome, flash, adobe

I tried to install it directly from the software center but on installing it I got this message in the terminal

```
Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package. 

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate
```

Please Help...

Comment: Google Chrome should come pre-installed with flash player. Are you using Chrome, or Chromium?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install flash to Google Chrome.  It is already there.

NPAPI plugin will not work, and `pepperflash` is already installed in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Since, Google Chrome is not an open source software therefore these plugins won't work it.
If you still want to use Google Chrome you can try Chromium Browser which is available in ubuntu software center which exactly works like Google chrome but with some pros.
To setup adobe flash player plugin is simple
    sudo apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Or you can try installing pepper plugin

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```